# Perform multiple replacement with pandas in one line of code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I want to change my data as follows:

```
"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"
```

Currently, I am using the code:

```
energy.Country[energy.Country == "Republic of Korea"] = "South Korea"
energy.Country[energy.Country == "United States of America"] = "United States"
energy.Country[energy.Country == "United
               Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"] = "United Kingdom"
energy.Country[energy.Country == "China, 
               Hong Kong Special Administrative Region"] ="Hong Kong"`
```

I tried using the `.replace` method to do the same, by passing the arguments as a dictionary:

`energy.replace('Country' : {"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"})`

But it does not seem to work, is there a more clean and tidy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `replace` on the *`Series`*, it's just easier.

```
repl_dict = {"Republic of Korea": "South Korea", ...}
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].replace(repl_dict)
```

Note, this is not a good place to use `map`, because entries in "Country" that do not map to anything in `repl_dict` will be replaced with NaN.

---

Another option is list-comp based replacement:

```
energy['Country'] = [
    repl_dict.get(x, x) for x in energy['Country'].tolist()]
```

Not as succinct as `replace`, but definitely very competent in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yes, it is more convenient and works great.